# Spring Security: hasRole not working & AuthenticaionPrincipal is null

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-test

I have a PUT mapped controller method which should be restricted to users with ROLE_BUYER role.
However during testing it is returing 200 OK to users without that role.
The controller method is getting called but both the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` and `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` are `null`.

The controller:

```
@PutMapping("{bookId}/borrow/{userId}")
public boolean borrowBook(@PathVariable("bookId") long bookId, @PathVariable("userId") long userId, @AuthenticationPrincipal(errorOnInvalidType=true) UserDetails user) {
    return bookService.borrowBook(bookId,userId);
}
```

The Security Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class LibrarySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/**").hasRole("LIBRARIAN")
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/**").permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }   
}
```

The test method:

```
@Test
public void borrowBookwithNormalUser() throws Exception {

    var userId = gilbert.getId();
    assertThat(gilbert.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_LIBRARIAN"))).isFalse();

    mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .put("/books/2/borrow/"+userId)
            .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(gilbert))
    ).andExpect(
        MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isForbidden()
    );

}
```

Here is the test setup :

```
@SpringBootTest
public class BookControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService uds;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private LibraryUser gilbert;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .build();
        gilbert = (LibraryUser)uds.loadUserByUsername("gilbert");
    }
```

`LibraryUser` is an entity that implements `UserDetails`.

```
@Entity
public class LibraryUser implements Serializable, UserDetails {

   @Id
   private long id;    

   @Column(unique=true)
   private String username

   private String password;

   private boolean library = false;

   public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
       var res = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
       res.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
       if(librarian) {
           res.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_LIBRARIAN"));
       }
       return res;
   }
}
```

Is it a problem with the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or the test itself ?

Comment: where is your login code?

Comment: There isn't one, just the test. I thought SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user() created a logged in user. It isn't the case ?

Comment: well that depends on how you set up your tests, you have provided way to little code, without any way for us to know how the instrumentation is set up. I suggest you read up in the spring security reference manual and make sure you have done all the steps https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test-mockmvc-setup

Comment: if you still can't find the problem, then i suggest you update your code with an actually fully running example, including full debug logs when the test is run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Toerktumlare, I found out that the problem was in my test setup.
It was missing `.apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())`. Here is the complete test setup:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(context)
        .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
        .build();
    gilbert = (LibraryUser)uds.loadUserByUsername("gilbert");
}
```

PS: Not sure, if this should be an edit/comment/answer.